# In mongodb, how to copy a document from a collection to another collection as the value of some key?

Tags: mongodb

for example,

```
collection Author:
{  {"name":"victor", "article":null}   }

collection Article:
{   {"name":"Tomorrow", "pages":396}   }
```

now I need to copy the document in Article to the Author, as the value  of the field  'article' of 'victor'.

How? I dont find prompt method in the mongodb manual.

In Python, preferably.

Comment: "how to copy ..." - break the problem into smaller parts. 1) you need to read an article; 2) you need to update author (set a field). Both operations are well covered in the docs.

Comment: What is your expectation output..??

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to join data from different collection authors and articles.

You can achieve this using mongodb [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).